# Combine Tables User Session Login

Tags: security, session, symfony, entity

I log in perfectly with the entity User. When I log in, I can get to user via Security.Context. Can I include another table, e.g. UserSettings to security.context? What I have to do in entity User.php.

My entity User.php:

```
<?php

namespace Frontend\AccountBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\DisabledException;

/**
* User
*
* @ORM\Table(name="user")
* @ORM\Entity
* @UniqueEntity("email")
*/
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;
...
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
...
```

My UserSettings.php:

```
<?php

namespace Frontend\AccountBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* UserSettings
*
* @ORM\Table(name="user_settings")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class UserSettings
{
/**
 * @var \Language
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Language")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="locale", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $locale;

/**
 * @var \User
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $id;



/**
 * Set locale
 *
 * @param \Frontend\AccountBundle\Entity\Language $locale
 * @return UserSettings
 */
public function setLocale(\Frontend\AccountBundle\Entity\Language $locale = null)
{
    $this->locale = $locale;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get locale
 *
 * @return \Frontend\AccountBundle\Entity\Language 
 */
public function getLocale()
{
    return $this->locale;
}

/**
 * Set id
 *
 * @param \Frontend\AccountBundle\Entity\User $id
 * @return UserSettings
 */
public function setId(\Frontend\AccountBundle\Entity\User $id)
{
    $this->id = $id;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return \Frontend\AccountBundle\Entity\User 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
}
```

Comment: You can do this just by relating these two table which seems to be OneToOne relationship; though when you get user object from `security.context` you will be able to get the settings for that user, too

Comment: Then how do I get it? ...->getUser()->getUserSettings()... is not available. I don't have anything in the entity User.php about the entity UserSettings.php, so that there is no relation between these two tables.

Comment: That's what I said, through the entities add(create) a relation property; the reason I don't give you answer is that I wanted to make sure is there any possible relationship between (logically not in code) so that I prepare some code example which may help you